# Camel route with a dynamic timer?

Tags: apache-camel

I need to repeatedly refresh a token based on its contained expiry value. Is there a way in camel to setup a route using a timer (or Quartz) to refresh the token then set the next date/time for the route to be triggered again?

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

No the easiest way is likely just a timer/quartz and then use a filter to then only call the refresh token at that time you want. You can then use a shared bean to store the state of the next time which you can use in the filter to compute whether to trigger the filter or not.

Comment: Lol - that's very similar to what I'm doing. I was hoping for a better way.